# How to extend ListActivity without declaring ListView in XML layout in android

Tags: android

Hi guys iam developing a Screen in android.Iam writing code for that screen to work both in Portrait and Landscape orientation.Here my Portrait and Landscape XML is different,that is why iam using different XML Files for both Portrait and Landscape orientaion.Here i included that these XML Files in onConfigurationChanged() method.Depending upon the orientation change iam including that specific XML File and iam using only one activity for this which extends ListActivity.In the Portrait orientation iam using ListView but in the Landscape orientation iam not using ListView.When iam changing my orientation from Portrait to Landscape it is giving an Exception saying that Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.Here i understand the problem that in my Landscape XML File i have not used the ListView as i extended ListActivity.But i dont want to use ListView.How can i overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can entirely avoid this issue. A `ListActivity` absolutely requires that there be a `ListView` in the layout with an id of `@android:id/list` (or `android.R.id.list` in code).

One hack that you might try is to define your landscape layout so that it has a `ListView` but force the `ListView` to have zero height. The `ListActivity` will be satisfied and yet it won't show on the screen.

By the way, if you aren't using the configuration-dependent resource directories (`res/layout-port` and `res/layout-land`), you should. The framework will automatically bind the correct layout file to the layout id you use and you don't have to select between them in code. See the guide topic [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).